# volatile vs threadLocal in java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, thread-local

Lets take SimpleDateFormat as an example since it is not thread safe.

I could allow each thread to have its own copy of SimpleDateFormat using threadLocal like this:

```
 private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue()
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    }
};
```

But the volatile keyword guarantees that a thread will have the most recent copy of the variable. So could i not do this instead:

```
volatile SimpleDateFormat myformatter;
```

and achieve the same thread safety ?

Comment: Because that's not where the thread safety issue occurs: the thread safety problem is that `SimpleDateFormat` has mutable state, which is independent of whether the reference is stored in a volatile field.

Comment: Thread-local and `volatile` do not do the same! With thread-local, there is a separate copy of the variable for each thread. With `volatile`, all threads share one variable. Making the variable `volatile` does not make it thread-safe, because `SimpleDateFormat` has internal state that must not be updated by multiple threads concurrently, as Andy mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the volatile keyword guarantees that a thread will have the most recent copy of the variable

Of the volatile variable *only*, not its fields.

Also, `volatile` is only useful if you need to change the value of the variable. In your use case, `final` looks like it would be more appropriate:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat format = ...
```

This also guarantees that you will have the most recent value of the variable - because it can only be assigned its value once, and `static final` has guarantees the visibility once the class is fully loaded.

---

But this isn't the reason why `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe anyway: it has mutable state which it uses to store intermediate values when formatting the date.

If one thread calls `format` while another is also in the `format` method for the same `SimpleDateFormatter` instance, these intermediate variables get stomped unpredictably, leading to interference between the threads, and hence unpredictable output.

It doesn't matter whether or not the values of these intermediate variables are up-to-date when read/written by another thread - their updating can be interspersed.

In short, `volatile` doesn't prevent thread interference, and so is not an appropriate alternative to a `ThreadLocal` here.

Comment: `Of the volatile variable only, not its fields.`---this is actually imprecise, even misleading, because you'll observe all the writes to the referred object's fields that the writing thread did before writing to the `volatile` field. This is the essence of safe publication.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik really? What I am think of is something like `System.out.println(volatileField.nonVolatileField);` - the read of `volatileField` might give you visibility of all writes to `nonVolatileField` up to that point; but can't `nonVolatileField` then be updated between reading `volatileField` and `volatileField.nonVolatileField`?

Comment: Yes, that's why I say you wording is "misleading", not "incorrect". It sounds like you don't get _any_ guarantees except for the `volatile` reference itself. On the flip side, you _don't_ get the guarantee of observing the "most recent" state of the `volatile` field because "most recent" isn't even a well-defined concept in the JMM. The essential difference is that of sequential consistency vs. linearizability.

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadLocal` is a facility which enables threads to have their own local copy of an object.  ThreadLocals are best used with objects that can be thread safe within a thread safety policy of *thread confinement* (even for many objects that are not "thread safe", thread safe usage is still possible as long as no reference to them leaks out from the confining thread).  ThreadLocals can not help with thread safe usage for mutable objects that are shared outside the thread that instantiates them.

The `volatile` keyword is used to provide a weak form of thread safety with a variable that may accessed by many different threads.  A key difference is that ThreadLocals are most typically not accessed by more than one thread.

Broadly speaking, thread safety requires both visibility (the most recent updates to the variable should be visible to other threads) and mutual exclusion (state transitions must be atomic so that state can not be observed to be inconsistent).  `Volatile` works with the Java Memory Model to guarantee that the variable will be visible, but it provides no form of mutual exclusion and therefore does not provide atomicity to state transitions in objects.

Because `volatile` and `ThreadLocal` are so different, there really is no common circumstance in which you'd be able to substitute one for the other.

Answer (score 0):

You do not achieve same thread safety with `volatile` because same instance of `SimpleDateFormat` will be used in different thread.